# How to add more fields to aws cost explorer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

In the aws billing dashboard, how to add extra columns(tags added) while generating the report?

When I checked it is only adding the field, total cost.

Comment: Do you mean Cost Explorer? Which billing dashboard? are you using filters or group by?

Comment: And what is the desired outcome? it's not clear what you're trying to do here

Comment: I have two tags.created..need to have both in the report generated

Comment: Did you enable them in Cost allocation tags under the billing service? In order for tags to be in the reports you need to mark them there

Comment: yeah already added.